# MariaDB subqueries: Unknown column in where clause

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery

I tried to build a subquery, but I got an error: `Unknown column 'p.id' in where clause.`

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM `properties` p,
     
     (SELECT * 
      FROM `property_owners` po 
      WHERE property_id = p.id 
      ORDER BY po.id DESC LIMIT 1) `owner_now`,
     
     (SELECT *
      FROM `property_owners` po
      WHERE property_id = p.id
        AND po.id != (SELECT MAX(poo.id) FROM `property_owners` poo)) `prev_owner`,

     (SELECT SUM(monthly_rental) as `mons`, SUM(deposit) as `deps`, SUM(area) as `areas`
      FROM `rental_histories`
      WHERE property_id = p.id
      GROUP BY property_id) `rental`,

     (SELECT SUM(area) as `land_area`
      FROM `property_land_specifics`
      WHERE property_id = p.id
      GROUP BY property_id) `land_specifics`

INNER JOIN `users` u ON u.id = p.user_id
INNER JOIN `property_prices` pp ON pp.property_id = p.id
INNER JOIN `property_lands` pl ON pl.property_id = p.id
INNER JOIN `land_usages` lu on pl.usage_id = lu.id

WHERE ...
```

Error: 1054-42S22: Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'
SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22 
(conn=1101) Unknown column 'p.id' in 'where clause'

I've read many solutions that I found on the internet. For example, it says I have to move my subquery to `JOIN` instead of inside `FROM`. But, the problem is, what if I have to get the aggregate value from other tables, like the `rental` and `land_specifics` table?

Comment: Explicit JOIN's are evaluated before comma separated, implicit ones. I.e. `u ON u.id = p.user_id` has no access to p.

Comment: The general advice is to use explicit JOIN syntax everywhere.

Comment: @jarlh Those `INNER JOIN` doesn't give any error. Even though I comment on all the `JOIN` syntaxes, the problem still comes up with the same error message. The problem must be on the subqueries.

Comment: I'd say both are having problems... You need a `LATERAL` _derived table_ (the subquery), to reference a table from the same `FROM` clause. I.e. try `LATERAL (SELECT ... WHERE property_id = p.id...)`. However, I do not if Mariadb supports those.